# File from abs path is not instantiated correctly

Tags: java, java-io

I have a simple method that checks if a path is directory with some files.
Although the folder is there with many files in it, the checks fail.

```
public boolean check() throws FileNotFoundException {
        LOG.info("getPath, prefix set to : {}", prefix);
        File templatesFolder = new File(prefix);
        if (!templatesFolder.isDirectory() || templatesFolder.list() == null || templatesFolder.list().length == 0) {
            LOG.error("Templates cannot be found in absolute path {}", templatesFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            LOG.error("templatesFolder.isDirectory() {}", templatesFolder.isDirectory());

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
prefix set to : file:///tmp/templates/
Templates cannot be found in absolute path /home/oozen/workspace/pdfGenerator/file:/tmp/templates
isDirectory false
```

How should I set the path so the checks do not fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you are using is considered a URI: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

This should fix your problem:

```
File templatesFolder = new File(new URI(prefix));
```